# How to get rid of 'outline' for all host elements?

Tags: angular

If one does something like

```xml
<mat-card [routerLink]="[`item/${itemId}`]">
  <!-- Content -->
</mat-card>
```

the card will be clickable, but there will also be an outline around the card. It seems to me I have to set an addtional style

```xml
<mat-card [routerLink]="[`item/${itemId}`]" [style.outline]="'none'">
  <!-- Content -->
</mat-card>
```

or

```
mat-card {
  outline: none;
}
```

to remove this. However, this gets tedious if I create other components because I have to set `outline: none;` everytime I want to make it a routed element from outside.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'another-card',
  styles: [`
    :host {
      outline: none;
    }
  `],
  template:`
    <div>
      <!-- Content -->
    </div>
  `
})
export class AnotherCardComponent {
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to globally set styles for host elements.

> [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxveb4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a few different approaches:

## 1. Globally

You can set the style globally:

```
* {
  outline: none;
}
```

## 2. For routerLink

If you want to apply it only when `routerLink` is used, you can also create a custom directive with the same selector:

```js
@Directive({
  // By using the same selector, this directive is applied when
  // routerLink is used without having to add anything else
  selector: "[routerLink]",
})
export class RemoveOutlineDirective {

  @HostBinding("class.no-outline")
  public removeOutline = true;

}
```

with

```
.no-outline {
  outline: none;
}
```

## 3. Externalize style

You can create a shared `hosts.styles.css` file and include that in all components:

```
:host {
  outline: none;
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: "app-example",
  styleUrls: ["../path/to/hosts.styles.css", "./app-example.css"],
})
export class AppExampleComponent {}
```

---

All of this said, consider carefully whether you really want to do this generically. The outline can be important for users with disabilities or keyboard-oriented users. Removing it may not be the best idea, you could also consider styling it to the needs of your application.

Comment: Awesome answer and thanks you for the advice to be careful with that! +1 for using `<!-- language: xxx -->`!